# How do I write a simple test using pytest-bdd and pytest using python?

Tags: python-3.x, bdd, pytest, webautomation

I am quite new to BDD. I have installed `pytest-bdd` with `python 3.6` in Windows7. Can some one give simple example of test of `pytest-bdd`implementation? I am not able to find proper solution for this on internet.

Comment: Given the example linked to below, is there something in particular that is tripping you up? Do you need guidance on directory structure? Running the tests? Continuous integration? Let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have an example in their documentation, [here](http://pytest-bdd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#example). In it, the lay out the creation of a 'feature file,' which seems to be (I admittedly haven't used pytest-bdd) where they piggyback off of pytest, which discovers the file by its name, 'test_publish_article.py'. Each feature file seems intended to isolate a single feature via it's described behavior ('given', 'and', 'when', 'then'), which is programmatically provided by decorators, e.g. @given(). Since this particular example is looking at the behavior of a website, upon which actions can be simulated via [splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), it seems they're grabbing a 'browser' fixture from [pytest-splinter](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-splinter) to integrate pytest with splinter.

Is that helpful, or do you need more?

Comment: I am reading the same, although feature file and decorators are new for me, I am trying to understand the same and will post additional queries if any. Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: @Python_Novice Okay, no worries! If this answers your question about finding an example for pytest-bdd, be sure to accept it as the answer. If it leads to additional questions about how to use decorators and so on, don't be afraid to post a new question about what is now causing you difficulties and tag me in it, so I can offer any insight I might have. Happy to help :)

Comment: I am not able to launch the browser using `pytest-bdd`. Could you please let me know how to write a feature file and .py file for the same to launch https://www.gmail.com and login with valid credentials? 
Also please specify how to run feature file. I am using `pytest test_file.py` (I have `test.feature` in the same directory) to run feature file right now, please let me know I am doing it right.

Comment: Can anyone please say how do I then run the test?(feature file + python file)?
I have followed the documentation, wrote those files, but don't know how to run it.